# Mediaconverter indicates “FX Link” up - does this mean that the Tx/Rx wavelengths of SFP module are ok?

Tags: fiber

Connected the FTTH socket from ISP with a LC Singlemode BiDi SFP module inserted into a TP-Link MC220L media converter. The "LINK" light is on for the FX (fiber) interface on the MC220L - can I then assume that the Tx / Rx wavelength of the SFP optics are compliant to the ISP infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

If your FX Link LED is on, it would seem you are connected!

---

## Offical FAQ

According to [TP-Link's official FAQ for the MC220L](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1135/):

> After FX ports are also connected, the FX LINK LED will go on as [shown in this picture](https://static.tp-link.com/res/upfile/faq/20160520063821.jpg), and the TP RX light will blink when there is data transmission.

Ensure you have matched the Tx and Rx:

> On the SFP module, you can see two triangles as is [noted in this picture](https://static.tp-link.com/res/upfile/faq/20160520063748.jpg), the pole towards outside means Tx (Transmit) port while the pole towards inside means Rx (Receive) port. **When we connect the SFPs,we need to make sure the Tx and Rx are matched on both sides, which means Tx <--> Rx, Rx <--> Tx.**

You can also refer to the disclaimer:

> Our SFP/Media Converter/Switches are in line with the industry standard and have no any detection code or any other detection mechanism, but **some other vendors may limit their models to only cooperate with their own devices**. If you want to use our SFP/Media Converter/Switches with some other vendors' devices together, please contact with their supporter to check if there are any detection design or can cooperate with other vendors' switch.